# JQuery expand and collapse row div

Tags: html, jquery, css

I ve a div based table which is loading data dynamically in rows. I m trying to apply Expand and Collapse feature to make view more user friendly and easy to ready which is required.

But i am having some issue. Onclicking Black row which contains New, Confirm etc hide only 1st row but not rest. Whereas i m looking to hide each row which are group by under (Black Row) like **New, Confirm, Freed, Cancelled**

```js
$(".pointer").click(function() {

  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $header.next();
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $header.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
      return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.orders {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.header-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #868686;
  color: white;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orders .order-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.orders .col.start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.orders .col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="orders">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="col start">Name</div>
    <div class="col center">Date/Time</div>
    <div class="col center">Phone</div>
    <div class="col center">PAX</div>
    <div class="col center">Description</div>
    <div class="col center">Table</div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: black;color: white;font-weight: bolder;" class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start"><span>New</span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="27" data-order-id="27">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="27" data-order-id="27">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="27" data-order-id="27">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="27" data-order-id="27">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="27" data-order-id="27">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="27" data-order-id="27">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="27" data-order-id="27">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="27" data-order-id="27">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="27" data-order-id="27">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="27" data-order-id="27">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="27" data-order-id="27">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="27" data-order-id="27">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="27" data-order-id="27">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="27" data-order-id="27">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="27" data-order-id="27">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="27" data-order-id="27">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="27" data-order-id="27">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="27" data-order-id="27">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="27" data-order-id="27">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="27" data-order-id="27">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="27" data-order-id="27">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="27" data-order-id="27">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="27" data-order-id="27">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state validate" id="27" data-id="27" data-order-id="27">Validate</button><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="27" data-id="27" data-order-id="27">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: black;color: white;font-weight: bolder;" class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start"><span>Confirm</span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-06-17 12:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="24" data-order-id="24">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="24" data-order-id="24">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="24" data-order-id="24">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="24" data-order-id="24">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="24" data-order-id="24">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="24" data-order-id="24">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="24" data-order-id="24">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="24" data-order-id="24">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="24" data-order-id="24">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="24" data-order-id="24">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="24" data-order-id="24">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="24" data-order-id="24">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="24" data-order-id="24">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="24" data-order-id="24">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="24" data-order-id="24">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="24" data-order-id="24">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="24" data-order-id="24">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="24" data-order-id="24">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="24" data-order-id="24">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="24" data-order-id="24">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="24" data-order-id="24">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="24" data-order-id="24">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="24" data-order-id="24">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" id="24" data-id="24" data-order-id="24">Free</button><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="24" data-id="24" data-order-id="24">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="25" data-order-id="25">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="25" data-order-id="25">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="25" data-order-id="25">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="25" data-order-id="25">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="25" data-order-id="25">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="25" data-order-id="25">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="25" data-order-id="25">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="25" data-order-id="25">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="25" data-order-id="25">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="25" data-order-id="25">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="25" data-order-id="25">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="25" data-order-id="25">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="25" data-order-id="25">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="25" data-order-id="25">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="25" data-order-id="25">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="25" data-order-id="25">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="25" data-order-id="25">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="25" data-order-id="25">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="25" data-order-id="25">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="25" data-order-id="25">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="25" data-order-id="25">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="25" data-order-id="25">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="25" data-order-id="25">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" id="25" data-id="25" data-order-id="25">Free</button><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="25" data-id="25" data-order-id="25">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: black;color: white;font-weight: bolder;" class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start"><span>Freed</span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-06-23 10:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">sss asxaa</span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="10" data-order-id="10">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="10" data-order-id="10" selected="">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="10" data-order-id="10">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="10" data-order-id="10">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="10" data-order-id="10">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="10" data-order-id="10">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="10" data-order-id="10">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="10" data-order-id="10">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="10" data-order-id="10">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="10" data-order-id="10">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="10" data-order-id="10">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="10" data-order-id="10">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="10" data-order-id="10">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="10" data-order-id="10">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="10" data-order-id="10">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="10" data-order-id="10">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="10" data-order-id="10">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="10" data-order-id="10">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="10" data-order-id="10">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="10" data-order-id="10">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="10" data-order-id="10">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="10" data-order-id="10">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="10" data-order-id="10">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="10" data-id="10" data-order-id="10">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-06-06 01:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="22" data-order-id="22">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="22" data-order-id="22">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="22" data-order-id="22">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="22" data-order-id="22">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="22" data-order-id="22">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="22" data-order-id="22">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="22" data-order-id="22">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="22" data-order-id="22">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="22" data-order-id="22">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="22" data-order-id="22">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="22" data-order-id="22">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="22" data-order-id="22">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="22" data-order-id="22">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="22" data-order-id="22">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="22" data-order-id="22">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="22" data-order-id="22">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="22" data-order-id="22">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="22" data-order-id="22">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="22" data-order-id="22">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="22" data-order-id="22">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="22" data-order-id="22">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="22" data-order-id="22">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="22" data-order-id="22">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="22" data-id="22" data-order-id="22">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-06-17 12:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">sssss</span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="23" data-order-id="23">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="23" data-order-id="23">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="23" data-order-id="23">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="23" data-order-id="23">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="23" data-order-id="23">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="23" data-order-id="23">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="23" data-order-id="23">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="23" data-order-id="23">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="23" data-order-id="23">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="23" data-order-id="23">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="23" data-order-id="23">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="23" data-order-id="23">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="23" data-order-id="23">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="23" data-order-id="23">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="23" data-order-id="23">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="23" data-order-id="23">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="23" data-order-id="23">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="23" data-order-id="23">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="23" data-order-id="23">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="23" data-order-id="23">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="23" data-order-id="23">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="23" data-order-id="23">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="23" data-order-id="23">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="23" data-id="23" data-order-id="23">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 12:45:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">codemaker36@gmail.com</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">s</span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="33" data-order-id="33">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="33" data-order-id="33">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="33" data-order-id="33">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="33" data-order-id="33">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="33" data-order-id="33">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="33" data-order-id="33">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="33" data-order-id="33">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="33" data-order-id="33">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="33" data-order-id="33">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="33" data-order-id="33">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="33" data-order-id="33">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="33" data-order-id="33">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="33" data-order-id="33">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="33" data-order-id="33">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="33" data-order-id="33">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="33" data-order-id="33">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="33" data-order-id="33">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="33" data-order-id="33">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="33" data-order-id="33">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="33" data-order-id="33">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="33" data-order-id="33">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="33" data-order-id="33">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="33" data-order-id="33">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="33" data-id="33" data-order-id="33">Free</button></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: black;color: white;font-weight: bolder;" class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start"><span>Cancelled</span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row pointer">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
    <div class="col start">
      <select name="pos_table_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" id="26" data-order-id="26">T1</option>
        <option value="2" id="26" data-order-id="26">T2</option>
        <option value="3" id="26" data-order-id="26">T3</option>
        <option value="4" id="26" data-order-id="26">T4</option>
        <option value="5" id="26" data-order-id="26">T5</option>
        <option value="6" id="26" data-order-id="26">T6</option>
        <option value="7" id="26" data-order-id="26">T7</option>
        <option value="8" id="26" data-order-id="26">T8</option>
        <option value="9" id="26" data-order-id="26">T9</option>
        <option value="10" id="26" data-order-id="26">T10</option>
        <option value="11" id="26" data-order-id="26">T11</option>
        <option value="12" id="26" data-order-id="26">T1</option>
        <option value="13" id="26" data-order-id="26">T2</option>
        <option value="14" id="26" data-order-id="26">T3</option>
        <option value="15" id="26" data-order-id="26">T4</option>
        <option value="16" id="26" data-order-id="26">T5</option>
        <option value="17" id="26" data-order-id="26">T6</option>
        <option value="18" id="26" data-order-id="26">T7</option>
        <option value="19" id="26" data-order-id="26">T8</option>
        <option value="20" id="26" data-order-id="26">T9</option>
        <option value="21" id="26" data-order-id="26">T10</option>
        <option value="22" id="26" data-order-id="26">T11</option>
        <option value="23" id="26" data-order-id="26">T12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col start"><button class="#{_item_class} state free" style="display:none;" id="26" data-id="26" data-order-id="26">Free</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea? What i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `$content = $header.next();` targets only first next sibling, not all of them.

I would suggest re-structure your HTML, so that header and content would be wrapped together by `.pointer`

```js
$(".pointer .header").click(function() {
  let parent = $(this).closest('.pointer');
  //getting the next element
  $content = parent.find('.content');
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    parent.find('.header-text').toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.orders {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.header-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #868686;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orders .order-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.orders .col.start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.orders .col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-text .header-status:before {
    content: '- Collapse';
    display: inline;
}

.header-text.active .header-status:before {
    content: '+ Expand';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="orders">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="col start">Name</div>
    <div class="col center">Date/Time</div>
    <div class="col center">Phone</div>
    <div class="col center">PAX</div>
    <div class="col center">Description</div>
    <div class="col center">Table</div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pointer">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start"><span class="header-text">New <span class="header-status"></span></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
        <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
        <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
        <div class="col center">1</div>
        <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pointer">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start"><span class="header-text">Confirm <span class="header-status"></span></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
        <div class="col start wide">2022-06-17 12:00:00</div>
        <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
        <div class="col center">1</div>
        <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
        <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
        <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
        <div class="col center">1</div>
        <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi small thing. I just want that if Black row is select then collapse or exapand shd work. Currently if i select white i can still see its collapsing or expanding

Comment: @codemaker Just change the selector that triggers click. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Just small question can i keep My existing Text with Expand and Collapse?

Like New +Expand+ then after click New -Collapse-

Comment: @codemaker Yes, change text for additional span element on header

Comment: $('span').text() ? like that?

Comment: Can u express plz?

Comment: @codemaker `$('.header-text span').text()`

Comment: in short i added in this: $content.is(":visible") ? $('.header-text span').text()+" Collapse" : $('.header-text span').text()+" Expand";

Comment: bt i cant get same text

Comment: @Justinas can u plz guide or express in example.....?? I m still nt able to succeed.

Comment: @codemaker Check update. I have replaced JS text replacement with CSS approach

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've assigned the `.pointer` class to each of the child rows in each group. When you click on one of the black rows, the code looks for the *next* element with the `.pointer` class - in your case, this is the first content row within that group - and hides it.

As @justinas has already said, you should wrap the content for each group in a container (e.g. a `<div>`), apply the `.pointer` class only to the header rows (the black rows) and in your `click` event handler for the header rows find the container and hide it.